# Access last user location from Google account using java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How do you access the user's Google Account last location in code? I am building an application that will that will need to get user address/general location and  to store data and I want to identify the last location of the person stored by Google using Google signups/login before submitting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't appear to provide this via API. I suggest you use the current device location or ask the user for their home city, or a country + TZ location. Alternatively, with some working around you may be able to access this dataset: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/types/Person
It contains "A contact location for a person's residence.", but the user needs to authenticate access to it.